# How to retrieve the cash dividends from the quantopian-quandl data bundle with Zipline?

Tags: quandl, data-ingestion, zipline, quantopian

https://www.zipline.io/bundles.html

> By default zipline comes with the quantopian-quandl data bundle which uses quandl’s WIKI dataset. The quandl data bundle includes daily pricing data, splits, cash dividends, and asset metadata. Quantopian has ingested the data from quandl and rebundled it to make ingestion much faster.

Is it possible to retrieve the cash dividends from the:

```
def handle_data(context, data):
```

function?